# Swing Component not displaying on the frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, layout-manager

I don't understand why the `RackBuilder` object I added to the `frame` does not get displayed.

The code runs and the `frame` gets generated. I expect to see a panel with 42 rows, each row containing a `JLabel` "test". Is there something incorrect/missing from my constructor?

```
public class RackBuilderTool extends JPanel{

    public RackBuilderTool() {
        super(new GridLayout(42, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            add(new JLabel("test"));
        }
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rack Builder Tool");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        RackBuilderTool rackBuilder = new RackBuilderTool();
        rackBuilder.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(rackBuilder);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

[image: Image of the output upon running the above code.]

Comment: All I see is the Java Frame.

Comment: Please post an image of the actual output.

Comment: close other projects you have opened, rebuild and recompile it again. Another option is: remove `extends JPanel` and create a `JPanel` object instead.

Comment: your code seems to work correctly for me once I add `package` and `import` statements to the top of RackBuilderTool.java .  JDK 1.6.0_43 on 64-bit Linux.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class RackBuilderTool extends JPanel{

    public RackBuilderTool() {
        super(new GridLayout(42, 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            add(new JLabel("test"));
        }
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rack Builder Tool");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        RackBuilderTool rackBuilder = new RackBuilderTool();
        rackBuilder.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(rackBuilder);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

now it will show you 42 rows of your label.

Answer (score 0):

Realized that the "run" button on Netbeans IDE is to run the entire project. As a result it was running another java file under the same project.

Once I right clicked on the java file I wanted to compile and clicked run it worked.

Thanks everyone for the help.